# Importing freely available Quantopian data into my own local, Python script?

Tags: python, quantopian

I have come across a [data set](https://www.quantopian.com/data/psychsignal/stocktwits) that looks very relevant to what I need.

The data set is provided through the online platform Quantopian, where you impot it into their existing Python environment. Is it possible at all to import this same data set API from Quantopian into a local Python script?

`pip install quantopian` does not exist.

`pip install quantopian-tools` [seems to be deprecated](https://github.com/Gitlitio/quantopian-tools), and does not seem to provide access to the data libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quantopian employee here.
Unfortunately, we can't make the data available off of our platform -- it is part of our agreements with the firms that provide us the data that we will not distribute it off the site. Hopefully you can try out what you have in mind in a Jupyter notebook on our platform in combination with the other data we have integrated? quantopian.com/notebooks

Alternatively, you could reach out to the nice folks at PsychSignal: https://psychsignal.com/contact/